# CMS module don't have the getExtensionAttriubtes and setExtensionattributes

Tags: magento2, rest-api, model

I am working on REST API for the cms block and adding some custom fields in the `cms_block` table. However, I didn't see the methods `getExtensionAttriubtes` and `setExtensionAttriubtes` in the CMS Block model. And Curious how can I achieve this if you don't have extension_attributes.